# Problem creating CodePipeline, Deploy stage for AWS SAM application

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-sam

I have created a working CodePipeline for my AWS SAM application.
It is using only **Source** and **Build** phases with the following `buildspec.yaml` file

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.7
    commands:
      - pip install --user aws-sam-cli
      - USER_BASE_PATH=$(python -m site --user-base)
      - export PATH=$PATH:$USER_BASE_PATH/bin
  build:
    commands:
      - sam build
  post_build:
    commands:
      sam package --s3-bucket deploy-bucket --output-template-file deployment.yaml
    # finally:
    #   sam deploy --template-file deployment.yaml --stack-name MyStackSAM--region us-east-1 --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

As you can see I have commented out the last two lines as I want to move that action to a **Deploy** stage in CodePipeline

My Deploy step looks like this:

[image: screensot]

My `CloudFormationPipelineServiceRole` has full admin permission at this point, never the less, I'm still getting the following error as the result of executing this stage.

```
Action execution failed
Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: XXXXFFFFFXXXX; S3 Extended Request ID: XXXXFFFFFXXXXFFFFFXXXXX=)
```

I am stuck as to why I'm getting this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `sam package` expects source template file that needs to be passed via `--template-file` flag. I don't see that template file anywhere in your code. Which template file are you trying to package?

Second, you are not uploading the necessary artifacts to the s3 bucket. The only thing that you are uploading is zipped code but as you can see from the command that you have commented out:

```
sam deploy --template-file deployment.yaml --stack-name MyStackSAM--region us-east-1 --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

you also need this file `deployment.yaml` but you didn't specify that in your code. There is no way for CodeBuild to guess which artifacts you want to preserve.

You will need to add additional `artifacts` section to the bottom of your buildspec file and specify those artifacts.

```
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - template.yaml             # (where do you have this file?)
    - outputtemplate.yaml       # (deployment.yaml in your case)
```

Note that the `artifacts` section needs to be on the same level as `version` and `phases`

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  ...
artifacts:
  ...
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! To answer your question regarding `template.yaml` I believe that `sam build` defaults to this specific name if nothing is specified. So I ended up adding only `deployment.yaml` to `files:` section and that did the trick. Thanks again!